# How to trim time string to specific format?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have a string that represents `datetime` but it has 9 digit numbers microseconds instead of 6.

```
'2022-05-09 08:02:18.106869456 +0000 UTC'
```

I'm looking for the best way to trim those 3 digits from the string in order to convert it to `datetime` object.

Comment: use a regex? Are you actually looking to parse this to datetime data type?

Comment: how it can be done using regex? yes, I want to parse it to datetime.

Comment: a simple `re.sub('(.+\.\d{6})(\d{3})(.+)', r'\1\3', s)` should do (removes the second group, the nanoseconds). String slicing as Piotr shows might be easier though. Or use dateutils' parser in case you're looking to parse to datetime anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you okay with lower precision?

Apply simple string operation to get rid of 3 extra digits and pass it to `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

```py
import datetime
t = '2022-05-09 08:02:18.106869456 +0000 UTC'
t2 = t[:26] + t[29:]  # made some assumptions about time string format
datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z %Z')
# expected output: datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 9, 8, 2, 18, 106869, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC'))
```

Comment: Which `python` version you're using? This code example works on my machine - `Python 3.8.2` on macOS 11.1. It also worked under `python 3.9.5` on this page https://www.python.org/shell/

Comment: Works fine on my Windows machine — so it not a Windows "thing" @FObersteiner.

Comment: @martineau nevermind, my mistake ;-) I mixed that up; it's actually pandas' to_datetime which complains.

Answer (score 0):

Pro You can use Regex to split each part of the string using this
[**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/wSVfr2/1)

```py
import re 
regex = r"""(?P<year>[0-9]{4})-(?P<month>[0-9]{2})-(?P<day>[0-9]{2})\s(?P<hour>[0-9]{2}):(?P<min>[0-9]{2}):(?P<sec>[0-9]{2}).(?P<micro>\d*)\s(?P<diff>[\+\-]\d+)\s(?
P<time_zone>\w+)"""

d = re.search(regex,'2022-05-09 08:02:18.106869456 +0000 UTC').groupdict()
print(d)
```

Then You can take what you want from the string

print:

```py
{'year': '2022', 'month': '05', 'day': '09', 'hour': '08', 'min': '02', 
'sec': '18', 'micro': '106869456', 'diff': '+0000', 'time_zone': 'UTC'}
```